# Time-dependent harmonic oscillator in classical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Consider a damped, driven harmonic oscillator:

$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \beta\frac{dx}{dt} + kx = F(t) $$

I want to write this equation for time-varying $m$, $\beta$ and $k$ which are the mass, viscous damping coefficient and spring coefficient respectively.

In some papers, for the time-varying version of this equation the authors simply write:

$$m(t)\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \beta(t)\frac{dx}{dt} + k(t)x = F(t) $$

however this seems not quite right to me because according to Newton's second law, force equals to the time-derivative of momentum, then for time-varying mass:

$$F= \frac{d}{dt}\left(m\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \frac{dm}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

So there should be an extra term in the equation:

$$m(t)\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \left(\beta(t)+\frac{dm}{dt}\right)\frac{dx}{dt} + k(t)x = F(t) $$

I am not sure whether there should be extra terms for time-varying $\beta$ and $k$ too.

In short, I would like to know what time-dependent harmonic oscillator equation looks like.

Answer (score 2):

I think your understanding of the matter is very much correct and the equation at the bottom is the one. Sooner or later - and maybe this is what the papers (silently?) do? - you will, for convenience, redefine $\beta$ to $\beta' = \beta + \frac{\text{d}m}{\text{d}t}$.

The way the model is built there will be no derivatives of products involving $\beta$ or $k$ and thus no extra terms for them.

Comment: So, there is no extra term coming from Hooke's law?

Comment: I would appreciate more if you (sketchily) prove this result or give a reference.

Comment: No, I mean, I think you understand the model, so this shouldn't be necessary. ;) But anyway: Friction force is a coefficient times velocity, to make it time-dependent make the coefficient time-dependent. What else? The force from Hooke's law is the product of a stiffness constant times position, to make it time-dependent...

Comment: For example, if you change some of the conditions, say we cool down the spring to change its material properties, then the stiffness of the spring, i.e. $k$, changes as a function of time. How this change goes - the physics behind, detailed modelling - is a different matter, in the context of the equation above for the damped oscillator we can take it as being given as a function of time.

Comment: On your example of spring cool-down, wouldn't it be easier if we model the change of k in detail and put it in the correct version of equation? Rather than re-modeling the behavior of the spring as a whole.

Comment: What is the equation of spring for arbitrarily changing coefficients? For example, k of my imaginary spring changes linearly in time, how do I calculate the response?